# Input[type="file"] doesnt work on ios 12.2

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, html-framework-7

I have application with input type="file" that works on ios 12.1 and previous but not in ios **12.2** (the newest one). Here is the code that I used:

```
<input ref="input" :accept="accept" type="file" @change="fileSelected">
```

It doesn't give any error when debug. I read some release document, Apple said they improve security for document and stuff in ios devices but didn't see any line for how to fix. I'm using **Framework 7 + Vue + Cordova**

Please anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work` ?

Comment: there is nothing happen when tap into the input field

Comment: actually that was about the new ios version treats uiwebkit differently I guess, same ```this.$refs.input.click();``` works on old ones but not in 12.2

Comment: What is the `:` before `accept` ? Could you remove it ?

Comment: it's vue syntax tho, you can but I pass a props in it so I used :

Comment: Does this one work with 12.2 on Safari ? And only with Cordova ?

Comment: I have the same problem, using cordova+ng-file-upload (but not vue). did you find a solution?

Comment: @MrJingles87 the problem for me was I triggered the upload file by js, somehow ios 12.2 wont let us trigger upload file by js function, when click directly to the upload button from input[type='file'], it works.

Comment: @NguyễnKhắcTâm: I can confirm that. The only solution for me was to put transparent file inputs over the normal upload button.

Comment: yeah, for me too, hacky but did the job

Comment: @MrJingles87 Can you provide an example? We're having this same issue, but not exactly sure on how you implemented your transparent file inputs.

Comment: just position a normal file input absolute over other upload button and make it transparent: <input style="position: absolute;left: 0;width: 100%;opacity: 0;" type="file" multiple ngf-select="uploadApi.onFileSelect($files)" />

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in UIWebview,
I solved this problem by replacing UIWebview with WKWebview。

Comment: Please give some code explaination to let others understand answer well.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try it

```
$timeout(function() {
   angular.element(document.querySelector('#example')).triggerHandler('click');
});
```

instead of

```
$timeout(function() {
   document.querySelector('#example').click();
});
```

this bug is replace with IOS 12.1.2 on Iphone XR too